# 'No route matches' error while using Factory Girl on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've been trying to use FactoryGirl for tests on my Rails application, but I'm running into difficulty with it.

I feel as if there must be something fairly obvious I'm doing wrong, but after much searching I haven't been able to figure out the cause.

I'm trying to run a test to confirm the 'show' action is successful on one of my controllers.

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: get 'show'
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"simple_requests"}
```

Below are the relevant code snippets leading to this outcome.

**/spec/controllers/simple_requests_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SimpleRequestsController do

  describe "GET 'show'" do

   before do
    @simple_request = build(:simple_request)
   end

  it "should be successful" do
      get 'show'
      expect(response).to be_success
    end

  end
end
```

**/factories/simple_requests_controller_spec.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :simple_request do
  id                          123
  full_name                   "Testie McTesterson"
  company                     "Test Company"
  role                        "Analyst"
  email                       "foobar@foobs.com"
  phone                       "000888"
  message                     "Test question?"
  end
end
```

**/controllers/simple_requests_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    authorize SimpleRequest #For pundit
    @simple_request = SimpleRequest.find(params[:id]) 
  end
```

I have two hypotheses as to why this may be happening:

1) Rspec is looking for an id for the 'show' action, but somehow can't find it. (Although there is one in the Factory, and I've yet to figure out how it wouldn't be flowing through.)

2) Pundit is causing issues, since the show action may require authorization (although commenting out the 'authorize' line makes no difference at present)

Any and all thoughts welcome :)

**EDIT**

Pasting below the output of rake routes | grep simple_requests

```
simple_requests GET    /simple_requests(.:format)          simple_requests#index
                POST   /simple_requests(.:format)          simple_requests#create
 new_simple_request GET    /simple_requests/new(.:format)      simple_requests#new
 edit_simple_request GET    /simple_requests/:id/edit(.:format) simple_requests#edit
 simple_request GET    /simple_requests/:id(.:format)      simple_requests#show
                     PATCH  /simple_requests/:id(.:format)      simple_requests#update
                     PUT    /simple_requests/:id(.:format)      simple_requests#update
                     DELETE /simple_requests/:id(.:format)      simple_requests#destroy
```

**Edit 2 - Adding ID parameter**

I have now also attempted to add an id as follows:

```
it "should be successful" do
  get 'show', id: @simple_request.id
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

This time I received the following error message

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find SimpleRequest with 'id'=123
```

'123' is the ID in my /factories - I think I must be missing something to get this working, but can't figure out what yet.

Comment: Post output of `rake routes | grep simple_requests`

Comment: You are missing the id param

Comment: @RAJ pasting as an edit in my initial post.

Comment: @AntarrByrd - it seems that's an issue somewhere, although on adding an ID param I still seem to have the error. Pasting comment in the edits - I seem to still be missing something here though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SimpleRequest does not have an Id. You need to use create instead of build

```
 before do
    @simple_request = create(:simple_request)
 end

 it "should be successful" do
   get 'show', id: @simple_request.id
   expect(response).to be_success
 end
```

Comment: That did it. When I uncommented the authorize line, this worked fine. I'll need to figure out how to make this work with Pundit authorization, but the specific question I asked on now seems to be answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
before do
  @simple_request = create :simple_request
end

it "should be successful" do
  get 'show', id: @simple_request.id
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

It's a `show` view, so you'll have to supply your request with an `ID` and you'll have to actually create a record with `create` instead of `build` in your `before` block.

Comment: Thanks for this - I suspected it might be something obvious like this! I tried doing this, but I still received an error (below). This is the ID in my factory girl object - have you got any further thoughts on how I could get it working?                                                             ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find SimpleRequest with 'id'=123

Comment: @Berun I've updated my answer. Instead of building your `SimpleRequest`, create it so that it actually save a `SimpleRequest` record in your database. Once that's done, it can be found by `SimpleRequest.find(params[:id])` in your `show` action. Your factory does have '123' as the ID, but there currently is no record in your database with that ID, that's why you get that error.